# Check is regex is valid via regex

Tags: regex, point-of-interest

Out of curiousity, is it possible to write a **regex**, which checks if other regexs are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible: regular expression execution model is not powerful enough for that.

In order for a regular expression string to be valid, all parentheses in the string must be balanced. Since [it is not theoretically possible to write a regular expression to verify if all parentheses in a string are balanced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/335858), it is also not possible to write a regular expression to check validity of a regular expression string.